# Unexpected behavior with Google Apps Script and jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I'm getting a behavior that I don't understand using jQuery, GAS, and the Google HTMLService.  I'm opening a modal dialog containing 'Dialog.html'.  In that file I have a button that I want to perform a function when clicked.

### Dialog.html

```
<form>
  <button id="foo">Foo</button>
</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    $( "#foo" ).click(google.script.run.myFunction());
  });
</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function myFunction(){
  Logger.log("I ran!");
}
```

When checking the logger, the function **is** called the moment the dialog is opened (which I don't want), but it **is not** called when the button is clicked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using NATIVE or IFRAME sandbox?  Have you tried switching to one or the other?

Comment: I've tried both NATIVE and IFRAME with no change in behavior.